# C# Entity Framework In Memory Db Relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, in-memory-database

I have a simple API which consists of three levels of data:

Accounts > Users > Addresses

The API is successfully loading the addresses for the users, but is throwing an exception determining the relationship between clients and users.

`Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ClientModel.Users' of type 'List<UserModel>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

Here are the models which look identical to me:

```
public class ClientModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public long Phone { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int AccountsCount { get; set; }
    public double AccountsBalance { get; set; }
    public double AccountsBalancePending { get; set; }
    public double AccountsDonations { get; set; }
    public double AccountsBalanceAch { get; set; }
    public double AccountsBalanceIra { get; set; }
    public List<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    public UserModel Advisor { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public ClientModel Client { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public bool Primary { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    public long Phone { get; set; }
    public List<AddressModel> Address { get; set; }
}

public class AddressModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }  
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public UserModel User { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }  
    public string StreetSecondary { get; set; }  
    public string City { get; set; }  
    public string State { get; set; }  
    public string Country { get; set; }  
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: You can map the relationship manually as it says, some inspiration and explanation can be found in this article: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Funny, I was just reading that article! I am going to try it out, but would prefer to at least figure out why the users > addresses works and clients > users throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship is not defined properly.How come it should be possible in your 
  `ClientModel` class.

```
public List<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
public UserModel Advisor { get; set; }
```

Entity framework will find this ambiguous to make relationship. Either it should be one to one or one to many. May be you are mixing things here. Just remove first or last(based on your requirement) and try to run this.

Comment: The challenge is that users entity uses single table inheritance, both the advisors and users(contacts) share the same table (or will). The client > advisor is a 1 to 1 relationship, while the client > users is a one to many. Would it be better to create a separate Advisor model, then handle the single table inheritance on the at the data access level? My goal here is to use the simplest, most conventional approach possible and avoid any custom configuration.

Comment: My goal here is to use the simplest, most conventional approach possible and avoid any custom configuration. - But you are making it complex for entity framework. you dont need a model for that make any flag in usermodel (eg isAdvisor ) to distinguish if both userModel and advisorModel is going to be same.

Comment: yeah, so if I am understanding you correctly you would recommend having a single collection of related users, then determine who is the advisor and who is the customer based on the role right?

Comment: Yes that should be part of role and it the correct way to define your model.